# making dynamic condition in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a dynamic array that represents columns in a table, and I have an array of rows in the table. I get the arrays as input in my angular 4 components and I don't know anything in the columns before I get them (should work on multiple types of variables).

Each column has a variable that says if it is mandatory or not and according to this I build a condition string that I want to run before I insert a new row to the array of rows or change an existing one.

I'm creating the condition in the ngInit, and after the creation it looks something like this:
`"(r.id == null) || (r.name == '')"` and so on (there could be && too)

I'm trying to bind the condition to the disabled attribute of a button, but I can't seem to convert it to a real.

How can I convert it to a condition so I could execute it and return true/ false accordingly?

I've already tried doing `[disabled]="[conditionVar]"`, and also tried using. 
`${condition}`, 
but those didn't work

my code looks something like this:
myComponent.ts:

```
export class Column {
title: string;
fieldName:string;
mandatory: boolean;
}

   @Component({
   selector: 'myComponent',
   templateUrl: './myComponent.component.html', 
   styleUrls: ['./myComponent.component.css']
})

export class MyComponentimplements OnInit {
   @Input() columns:Column[];
   @Input() rows;

   conditionString = "";

   constructor() { }
   ngOnInit() {
     for (let c of columns.filter(d=>d.mandatory)) {
       this.conditionString += "(r." + c['fieldName'] + " == null) || "; // 'r' is the name of the variable that i want to run the condition on
     }
     this.conditionString = this.conditionString.substr(0, this.conditionString.length - 4); // to remove the last ||
   }
}
```

myComponent.html:

```
<table>
...
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let r of rows">
      <td *ngFor="let c of columns">
        <input [(ngModel)]="r.[c.fieldName]">
      </td>
      <td *ngFor="let c of columns">
        <button [disabled]="here I want to bind my condition">save this row</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

(the user should edit the rows and if he want he can save the changes)
every thing works but the binding of the condition

Comment: Can we see the code please?

Comment: So you're saying that you save your condition as a string?

Comment: You can use **!!Condition**, this means your code ll looks like this => !!((r.id == null) || (r.name == ''))

Comment: the error is in line 23

Comment: @TomasVancoillie i added the code.

Comment: I'm not sure it will work - the condition is a string. `!!condition` will convert string to boolean (non-empty string will be `true`). I'm not sure if you can use a concatenated condition in data binding.